# AWX Job Scheduler not launching scheduled jobs

Tags: ansible-awx

I am using AWX to launch some anisble playbooks.
However the scheduler is not launhcing the jobs.

"rrule": "DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Paris:20230912T113000 RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;COUNT=1"

[Scheduler Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nj9Vp.png)

Thanks in advance

I tried to use different timezones like Paris/UTC. And jobs ran successfully when launched manually.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.